# Flex: I am new to programming field and I want to learn flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I can learn how to create a UI using this site:

http://examples.adobe.com/flex3/componentexplorer/explorer.html

But I want to know all the keywords used in this language I searched for keywords but could not find any useful stuff so if you had any useful links please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some resources to get you started:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/index.html

But I advise you to learn Flex 4.6 instead.

Answer (score 0):

Per [this link](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_13.html), hrere are the reserved keywords used in Flex / AS3:

```
as
break
case
catch
class
const
continue
default
delete
do
else
extends
false
finally
for
function
if
implements
import
in
instanceof
interface
internal
is
native
new
null
package
private
protected
public
return
super
switch
this
throw
to
true
try
typeof
use
var
void
while
with
```